# import React from 'react' vs import React from 'React'

Tags: reactjs, import, gulp

This line works:

```
import React from 'React'
```

but this not

```
import React from 'react'
```

What did I wrong, and why is the capital case needed?. I already reinstalled npm and before delete the complete node_modules folder.

To be a little bit clearer: It compiles the code, but on runtime for `require ('react')` <= the compiled code for the import statement, it comes the module not found, but `require ('React')` is working.

I am using gulp as build Tool

Comment: Hows your package.json looks like? When what does "This line works" mean? What is the error? Whats not working?

Comment: @DennisVash If I am doing with lowercase it comes with the Error: Cannot find module 'react' , otherwise it imports React. In the package Json react is in small letters.